# Binomial Approximation with power $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits, asymptotics

By binomial approximation, we have that $(1+x)^a=1+xa$ for large values of $a$, since $|ax|<<1$. Now suppose I have the following expression $$-B(1-\frac{x_1}{B})^{-1}$$
for some large value of $B$, we have that $|-\frac{x_1}{B}*-1|<<1$, hence may $(1-\frac{x_1}{B})^{-1}$ be approximated by $1+\frac{x_1}{B}$, such that the first expression is

$$-B(1-\frac{x_1}{B})^{-1}=-B(1+\frac{x_1}{B})$$

provided $B$ is sufficiently large?

---

$x_1$ is a small positive number (relative to $B$)

Comment: This is not at all clear.  $3^a=(1+2)^a$ is not equal to $1+2a$ for large $a$.  Maybe you are making assumptions about the magnitude of $x$, but why make your readers guess what assumptions you had in mind?

Comment: @lulu, the values are not given. I'm interested in what happens when $B$ gets large (relative to $x_1$).

Comment: But...what's the question?  The approximation $\frac 1{1-x}\approx 1+x$ for small $x$ is very well known.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I am. Sorry?

Comment: That approximation is just the first order of the geometric series $\frac 1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$.